# Auto scroll a chatbox with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a small chat functionality to so that my users can make comments during a video call session. I have a chatbox with the following function onkeypress which enable them to send the message.

I am unable to figure out one thing only now, that is how to make the chatbox auto scroll when each message is appended to the media.

```
var userMessage = function (name, text) {
    return ('<li class="media"> <div class="media-body"> <div class="media">' +
        '<div class="media-body"' +
        '<b>' + name + '</b> : ' + text +
        '<hr/> </div></div></div></li>'
    );
};

var sendMessage = function () {
    var userMessage = $('#userMessage').val();
    socket.emit('chatMessage', { message: userMessage, username: username });
    $('#userMessage').val("");
};

$('#userMessage').keypress(function (event) {

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        sendMessage();
    }

});
socket.on('chatMessage', function (data) {
    $('#chatbox-listMessages').append(userMessage(data.username, data.message));
});
```

I have my html in handlebars template to render the chat messages:

```
<!-- CHAT ROOM -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
      CHAT ROOM
      <span class="pull-right" id="chatbox-username">
        {{#if user}}
        {{user.name}}
        {{/if}}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="media-list" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll" id="chatbox-listMessages">

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type message and press Enter" id="userMessage" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          {{!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendMessage()">SEND</button> --}}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This so far works perfectly for me, when the user enters a message in the input and presses the enter key, the message is sent.

The problem I am having is how can I make the messages in the chatbox scroll up on each new message so that the the most recent message on the bottom is visible to the user.

Comment: Where is the code that receives the message and shows is in the DOM (*that is where you need to add the code to scroll*)

Comment: Its the userMessage function the first block of code. Can you help suggest what change should I make?

Comment: that code just creates the html to be inserted. But it does not insert it. You should have a `socket.on('chatMessage, ...)`. Post that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the scrolling after appending the new message in the DOM

so

```
socket.on('chatMessage', function (data) {
    var messages = $('#chatbox-listMessages'),
        messagesNode = messages[0];
    messages.append(userMessage(data.username, data.message));
    messagesNode.scrollTop = messagesNode.scrollHeight;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What about :

```
    $('#chatbox-listMessages').scrollTop($('#chatbox-listMessages').prop("scrollHeight"));
```

At the end of the sendMessage() function ?

Comment: Just tried that. It works partially. The messages are scrolling but not to the last message which is at the bottom.

Comment: @gabriele...yes I have that. Added to the original question.

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, it works perfectly now. Much appreciate your help.